# Prove that $\int_a^c f(x)\ dx = \int_a^b f(x)\ dx +\int_b^c f(x)\ dx$

Tags: integration

Suppose $a,b,c$ are constants, $a < b < c$. The interval $[a,c]$ is in the domain of $f$. Prove that

$$\int_a^c f(x)\ dx = \int_a^b f(x)\ dx+\int_b^c f(x)\ dx$$

This statement(property) is often stated in textbooks directly without proof. However, I encounter an assignment question which asks me to prove this statement using mathematical argument but not using a graph. I totally don't have any idea on how to prove the statement.

Comment: Again, please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As marty cohen has already stated, considering antiderivatives makes the work much easier.

Consider the integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$

Let $\phi (x)$ be an antiderivative of $f(x)$. Then-

$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\phi(b)-\phi(a)$ ... (i)

$\int_a^c f(x)dx=\phi(c)-\phi(a)$ ...(ii)

$\int_c^b f(x)dx=\phi(b)-\phi(c)$ ...(iii)

On adding (ii) and (iii),we have

$\int_a^c f(x)dx + \int_c^b f(x)dx=\phi(b)-\phi(a)=\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the definition of integral.

The easiest case would be if the integral is defined as the antiderivative.
Then the result follows from the antiderivative at b canceling out.

Riemann and Lebesgue I'll leave to others.

Answer (score -1):

I would consider the integral as approximated by a Riemann sum...

$$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx\approx \sum_a^b f(x)\ \Delta x$$

By definition, a sum is additive so...

$$\sum_a^b y+\sum_b^c y=\sum_a^c y$$

Ergo, by taking the limit $\Delta x\to0$...

$$\int_a^c f(x)\ dx = \int_a^b f(x)\ dx+\int_b^c f(x)\ dx$$

Comment: What did I do wrong?